# Upgraded from 13.0 to 14.04.3, it stuck on ubuntu loading page

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I have upgreaded to 14.04.3 and after successful install, it rebooted machine.

After reboot, the machine, keep showing UBNUTU load screen(purple background with 5 dots showing that it loading something)

Please help

Comment: Please edit with correct version (13.0 ??).. did you get any error during upgrade?

Comment: I am not very sure of 13.* version. When it was downloading and installing package there were not error.

Comment: Try reboot ... and select older kernel version from boot menu if it helps...and share error messages if any

Comment: With older kernel version also it's not going to login page , same issue. But on clicking alt+f1 it shows console. Is there way to check what's the issue

Answer (score 0):

USE GNOME

You can run Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome instead of unity.

@tty `(Ctrl + Alt + F1):`

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback

reboot
```

@login prompt:

```
Click the image on the upper right of the name
Select: GNOME Flashback (Metacity)
```

Comment: followed the steps, still the issue persist